# System too slow after minikube . (4gb ram + core i3 )

Tags: performance, kubernetes, minikube

I have a core i3 processor 7th generation and 4gb ram in my system. I installed virtual box and then ran .. minikube start on my shell.
As the minikube starts, the system is heavily slowed down. It hangs at the drop of hat. I am learning kubernetes and want to make use of yaml files to deploy and learn which I can't in playground .
And as I delete minikube , system comes back to life.
So, I have two questions. Is the issue with RAM or with core i3 ? The prerequisites for minikube is 2 CPUs . Does that mean minikube alone will have two CPUs for itself and host will not have any?
Whats causing the issue?
Second one, is there any other way i can learn k8 without minikube? playground doesn't provide way for adding yaml file

Comment: Do you have also installed docker?

Comment: yes, i have docker as well.

Comment: May be try microk8s over minikube. Or perhaps k3s.  If wsl is available,  directly try on wsl.  Minikube or microk8s both create their own vm internally.

Comment: Open a system monitor. If RAM is near of 100% then probably your memory is not enough. Swap usage is also a good indicator, and you will see a high usage of the hard disk too.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not enough memory so the machine starts paging/swapping. Not enough cpu is a problem, too, of course.

If you are using Windows try stopping all programs and docker desktop when using minikube. (minikube uses 2gb ram by default)
Try upgrading to at least 8gb ram when working with virtual maschine. (minikube and docker desktop both create VMs for the linux environment.)
If you are using a linux machine use the docker driver for minikube.